# Automapper - How to reuse objects instead of creating new ones (this objects are in a list)

Tags: automapper, entity-framework-4.1

I got the following problem:
I got a Entity (from EF Code First) that looks like this.

```
 public class Movie {
 public ICollection<AudioQuality> AudioQualities  {get;set;}
}

public class AudioQuality {
public Guid Id{get;set;}
public int Channels{get;set;}
}

//Automapper Init:
Mapper.CreateMap<Movie, MovieDto>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<MovieDto, Movie>().ForMember(dest => dest.AudioQualities,opt => opt.UseDestinationValue());


        Mapper.CreateMap<VideoQuality, VideoQualityDto>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<AudioQuality, AudioQaulityDto>();

        Mapper.CreateMap<VideoQualityDto, VideoQuality>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<AudioQaulityDto, AudioQuality>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Movies, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

And I also got a DTO that looks similar!

I map from the DTO to the Entity like so:

```
//Get Movie from DB and than update it with the dto values
Movie movieFromDb = GetMoviesWithAllChilds().Single(mov => mov.Id == movieDto.Id);

//use update the entity from db with dto
Mapper.Map(movieDto, movieFromDb);
```

Now the problem is, that Automapper creates a new AudioQuality-Object for each item in AudioQualities.

But I want that he just copies the values from the AudioQuality-Objects from the DTO to the Entities instead of creating new Objects with the values from the DTO.

Is there a way to do that??

FYI: UseDestinationValue works on the collection (so the collection is not copied).

br rene_r

Answer (score -1):

Get your entity from the context and pass it in to the Mapper function as the second parameter. The updates will eb applied from the source to the destination.

```
mapper.Map<SourceType, DestType>(source, dest);
```

Comment: Thats what I did with this lines: Movie movieFromDb = GetMoviesWithAllChilds().Single(mov => mov.Id == movieDto.Id);
Mapper.Map(movieDto, movieFromDb);